# java complains on loading pkcs dll from softhsm

Tags: java, windows, pkcs#11, softhsm

I am trying to use softhsm for my project using java 1.8-64bit.

I am trying with m first sample java class given  here [Connecting to SoftHSM java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009931/connecting-to-softhsm-java)

I was able to install softhsm [softhsm2-windows installer](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows).

And Also able to create token usng softhsm-util.exe tool.

but when I try to run the java code I am getting

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
                at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
                at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
                at SoftHSM.main(SoftHSM.java:44)
            Caused by: java.io.IOException: The specified module could not be found.
            Z:/SOFTHSM_INSTALL/lib/softhsm2-x64.dll
                at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.connect(Native Method)
                at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.<init>(PKCS11.java:138)
                at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:151)
                at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:313)
                ... 2 more
```

Even though the file is available in right location as mentioned in exception.

Please help to solve this issue.

Updated System Visual C++ installed:

[Visual C++ in My PC Win 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV2hb.png)

Comment: Does java have read access to that location?

Comment: Yes it has access . I tried to keep in system 32 and many other folders but not helpful

Comment: @Slok did you install both 32-bit and 64-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 on the target system?

Comment: I am just trying sample program which was mentioned above in my question. I was able to install SoftHSM and able to create slot and token inside that using cmd of windows.  But wanna do same operations from Java. Not getting much help...on this topic

Comment: @Slok I see your pain but you did not answer my question :) Do you have both 32-bit and 64-bit version of [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) installed on the target system?

Comment: Sorry, I have Win 64bit Windows 10 PC . May be no 32 bit I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR** : If you want to use `softhsm2-x64.dll` from your JAVA application then you need to install 64-bit version of [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

---

**Detailed answer** : You did install SoftHSM using [SoftHSM2 installer for MS Windows](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows).

All executables and libraries present in that package (including `softhsm2-util.exe`) are 32-bit expect for `softhsm2-x64.dll` which is 64-bit.

All executables and libraries present in that package (including `softhsm2-util.exe`) depend on 32-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 expect for `softhsm2-x64.dll` which depends on 64-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

[README.md](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows/blob/2.2.0/README.md) on project website says:

> These packages include both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PKCS#11
>   library and require both 32-bit and 64-bit version of [Visual C++
>   Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) to be installed on the target
>   system.

[README.txt](https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows/blob/2.2.0/SoftHSM/misc/README.txt#L11-L16) displayed after the installation says:

> This package includes both 32-bit and 64-bit build of SoftHSM 2.2.0
>   statically  linked to OpenSSL 1.1.0d. It requires both 32-bit and
>   64-bit version of Visual  C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015
>   to be installed on the target  system. These can be downloaded from:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

My advice: install both 32-bit and 64-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Will try and update you. FYI: I updated my visual c++ installed in PC above.  I cannot install x86 version of Visual C++ Redistributable 2015. But I installed now  64-bit version of Visual C++ Redistributable 2015.

Comment: Atleast now isue resolved Thanks jariq  :-)  , but it complains about slot number.  Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_SLOT_ID_INVALID

Comment: @Slok That seems to be a different issue of SunPKCS11 provider so IMO you should create new SO question or search existing questions/answers.

Comment: anyway great help. Thanks I can this from here now . Seems to be I am missing Slot creation...I will do that.